# не срабатывает KeyDown

Tags: c#, winforms, framework, таймер, keydown

Не срабатывает KeyDown ни для изменения интервала таймера, ни для чего-либо еще

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Figure d;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Gamefield g = new Gamefield(10, 20);
            g.Create_Gamefield(panel1);
            Figure f = new Figure(new int[] { 3, 0 },g.mas);
            d = f;
            d.Figure_Draw();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                timer1.Interval = 100;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            d.Figure_Update();
            d.Figure_Draw();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Отладочную печать туда добавляли, проверяли - попадает вообще туда управление? Ну или в отладчике breakpoint поставить попробовать.

Comment: Что за таймер? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?